# Canceling a "delete" event if "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, events

I am using `System.Data.EntityClient` NOT the simple `System.Data.SqlClient`

I am painfully new to Entity Framework so please forgive my ignorance and please don't offer cryptic responses as I my not have the background information necessary to make sense of them.

I have done several hours of research and cannot find the right combination of answers that solve my problem.

The Problem:

When the "delete" event is triggered the page throws this error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

I want to capture that error and have it instead populate a Label on the page that says

> This Customer cannot be deleted

My ASP page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<p>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="CustomerDetail" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="CustomerSqlDataSource" Height="50px" 
        Width="215px" Visible="False" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        OnModeChanged="CustomerDetail_ModeChanged">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name:" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name:" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City:" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
</p>
<asp:Button ID="NewCustomerButton" runat="server" Text="New Customer" OnClick="NewCustomerButton_Click" />
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="DeleteLabel" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"/>
    <asp:GridView ID="CustomerGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="CustomerId" DataSourceID="CustomerSqlDataSource" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="CustomerGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />

    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CustomerSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ITP236-InventoryConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customer] WHERE [CustomerId] = @CustomerId" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customer] ([FirstName], [LastName], [City], [State]) 
                        VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @City, @State)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerId], [FirstName], [LastName], [City], [State] FROM [Customer]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customer] 
                        SET [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [City] = @City, [State] = @State 
                        WHERE [CustomerId] = @CustomerId" OnDeleted="CustomerSqlDataSource_Deleted">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</p>
```

The code behind which is not working:

```
protected void CustomerSqlDataSource_Deleted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ExceptionHandled == false)
     {
      e.Command.Cancel();
      DeleteLabel.Visible = true;
      DeleteLabel.Text = "This Customer cannot be deleted";
     }
}
```

==============================================================================

Edited at 11:41am EST to include the entire error.  Although, I understand what the problem is,
I am simply trying to catch this error before it displays and bring it back to 
a label on the page and have the Label say "Customer cannot be deleted"

==============================================================================
Server Error in '/' Application.

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_SalesOrder_Customer". The conflict occurred in database "ITP236-Inventory", table "dbo.SalesOrder", column 'CustomerId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_SalesOrder_Customer". The conflict occurred in database "ITP236-Inventory", table "dbo.SalesOrder", column 'CustomerId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_SalesOrder_Customer". The conflict occurred in database "ITP236-Inventory", table "dbo.SalesOrder", column 'CustomerId'.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352418
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1406
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +380
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDelete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues) +568
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Delete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +84
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex) +930
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +974
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +205
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9671830
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

Comment: It looks like you are deleting the wrong data or in a wrong way. You probably need to delete something else first before removing a Customer. Your database does not allow it because of the mentioned constraint. It is not possible to give you the right answer without knowing what relations are between the `Customer` table an some other one(s).

Comment: You will not be able to handle the error in the `Deleted` event. That event fires after the deletion has successfully occurred. In your case, it doesn't successfully occur.

Comment: SO if I use: CustomerSqlDataSource_Deleting instead what would the code look like?  The C# intellisence wont give me: e.ExceptionHandled == false... because it never gets to an exception I suppose...

Comment: Sorry, there is none.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Are you sure? The documentation suggests that the `Deleted` event is raised after a deletion has completed, regardless of whether it has completed successfully.

Comment: You should post the full exception message.

Comment: I don't see where the documentation says the Deleted event is raised even on a foreign key constraint violation. If it is, then the OP should check `e.Exception != null` instead of checking `ExceptionHandled`.

Comment: the code will not accept -> e.Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is due to the violation of a foreign key constraint. The primary key of the `Customer` table is referenced in a foreign key constraint on some other table. You can't delete the customer because some other table depends on the customer.

For example, what if there were an `Orders` table that had a `CustomerId` column that referred to the customer you're trying to delete? Customers order products, so an order can't exist without a customer. In this case, try changing your DELETE statement:

```
DELETE FROM [Customer] WHERE [CustomerId] = @CustomerId
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Orders] AS o WHERE o.[CustomerId]=@CustomerId)
```

This will prevent the deletion of a customer who has orders. You can handle this in the `Deleted` event as follows:

```
protected void CustomerSqlDataSource_Deleted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
    {
        DeleteLabel.Visible = true;
        DeleteLabel.Text = "This Customer cannot be deleted because it has orders";
    }
}
```

---

You may be able to handle the exception by checking `e.Exception != null` instead of `e.ExceptionHandled == false`.

Comment: e.AffectedRows  does not seen to be an option for me. These are my 
<br><br>
using System;<br>
using System.Collections.Generic;<br>
using System.Linq;<br>
using System.Web;<br>
using System.Web.UI;<br>
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;<br>

Comment: See [AffectedRows property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.affectedrows.aspx).

Comment: public int AffectedRows { get; }     

so how would you use it?  You have it inside of a if statement this says it's a public int. I'm not sure who to make
-> public int AffectedRows { get; }  == to (e.AffectedRows == 0)

Comment: Just try the code I wrote. `AffectedRows` is a public `int` property of `e`.

Comment: Ok, so the third time I read through your solution and I had some one next to me (another programmer) so I was talking out loud to that person and I DID EVERYTHING you said to do. It worked! Whoo Hoo! PS: he told me a needed a rubber ducky on my desk.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void CustomerSqlDataSource_Deleted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
     try {
         if (e.ExceptionHandled == false)
         {
         e.Command.Cancel();
         DeleteLabel.Visible = true;
         DeleteLabel.Text = "This Customer cannot be deleted";
     }
     catch {
       // do your thing here when error occurs
     }
}
```

Comment: Putting a `try`...`catch` around code which doesn't throw an exception won't have any useful effect.